# Build failure, due to undefined symbol for architecture i386

Tags: xcode, build

I am not sure what changes in the app code, and I started seeing this build failures

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ProfileViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SystemViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code was building and running fine with iOS7.1 or 6.0, with Xcode 5. However, I was not sure of the changes, so I reverted everything. But still I am seeing this failure. It is pointing to the three classes, but at this point there is no changes in the thress classes,
`ProfileViewController`, `SystemViewController`, `LoginViewController`

Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are `ProfileViewController.m`, etc, added to the app target?

Comment: undefined reference means a linker error, so basically it doesn't matter if you changed the code. What matters are the changes to the make-file.

Comment: in my case .m file has missed in compile sources in build phases. Thank you very much.